# SimPy: TypeError: schedule() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to request a resource from a list and keep getting this error. 
My request looks like 
`SBReq = resources['signalBlocks'][i].request()`
where `signalBlocks` is a key to a dictionary with the value as resources in a list. It works fine when I use `Req = resources['otherKey'].request()` when the value is just a resource.

Comment: Hi, can you post the exact error code and a code snippet that produces the error?

Comment: proceed = self._do_put(put_event)
  File "C:\Users\U\Anaconda3\envs\daily.py\lib\site-packages\simpy\resources\resource.py", line 213, in _do_put
    event.succeed()
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Anaconda3\envs\average_bike_use_daily.py\lib\site-packages\simpy\events.py", line 178, in succeed
    self.env.schedule(self)
TypeError: schedule() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
And the code that causes it is ```SBReq = resources['signalBlocks'][i].request()``` where resources is a dictionary, ```signalBlocks``` is a key to a list value and i is an index in a list

Comment: That helped a little but not very much. A reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
would help make it easier to answer.
For example, I can't tell what the list `resources['signalBlocks']` contains. That might be the problem, but there's no way to tell unless there's a reproducible example